# Update statement with primary key duplicate

Tags: mysql

I have data across three tables. I'm trying to perform an action that moves data from one user to another - some of the data may not exist, and the destination may exist already and need to be overwritten. Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 USING (UserName)
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 USING (UserName)
SET t1.UserName = @newUser, t2.UserName = @newUser, t3.UserName = @newUser
WHERE t1.UserName = @oldUser
```

This works fine, except for if there is already data in the tables with the new username. I get (as you'd expect) a duplicate key error. Is there any solution to this that keeps it in a single SQL statement? I essentially want to mimic the functionality of INSERT...ON DUPLICATE UPDATE, but with an update statement instead. Is this doable, or do I need a separate statement to remove any existing entries first?

Comment: There is no way to say update or on duplicate key update as you are already performing an update. You should check if the new user exists before performing the update. I cannot imagine a scenario where anything good could come of allowing a user to be able to change their username to (someone elses) already existing username

Comment: What is the reason you can't use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` ?

Comment: Without getting into the actual scenario too deeply, this situation is expected. None of these three tables are the primary user table - they're essentially assigning users to tasks in T1, with task metadata in T2/T3. The way the system is designed, that metadata is created for all users in T2/T3 and then users can modify it - so if we're changing assignment (T1), we want the metadata associated with that user to go along with it, overwriting what may have been there.

Comment: @Vatev - because I'm reassigning existing data. If I did an INSERT...ON DUPLICATE, I'd have to do a separate select statement first, which would defeat the purpose of trying to do it in a single statement anyway.

Comment: You can insert the result from a select statement -  `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.

Comment: Seems to me your db schema is the problem,. normally you would have a unique id for a user which referenced their username rather than have a changeable item as the key on multiple tables that way you only ever update username in the one table everything else is referenced by the users ID

Comment: @Anigel you're right, the schema is definitely a problem, and fixing it is a longer term project that unfortunately is outside the scope of what I'm doing now :) When the system was originally designed, there was a 1:1 relationship between users/assignments, now multiple users can have the same assignment, which causes the issues described here when trying to move from one to another, along with others as well. Some day....

Comment: @Vatev - that would solve the issue of updating the existing data but it would also leave the old data in place which we don't want, correct? Sounds like two SQL statements is going to be the way to go here...

Comment: Can you please tell us precisely what you want to happen if `@newUser` already exists?

Comment: @OllieJones - basically, delete the entries that already exist for that key. Which is why it's starting to sound like a separate statement that first deletes those entries might be my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be wanting to do this in a transaction if your application has any possibility of multiple clients hitting it at the same time.  Your attempt to do it in a single statement is, in fact, an attempt to do it in a transaction.  But it seems your business rules are a little more complex than a single statement can implement.

First, do this to start your transaction. (Many language bindings to MySQL offer specific functions you can use in place of issuing this statement.)

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

Then, issue this query.  (It works in InnoDB, but not MyISAM.)  It puts a lock on the row for your user, if the @newUser name already exists.

```
  SELECT Username
    FROM Table1
   WHER Username = @newUser
     FOR UPDATE;
```

Then, from your application language, retrieve the count of rows here. It should be either zero (meaning this @newUser doesn't already exist) or one (meaning it does).  If the user does exist, delete.

```
  DELETE FROM Table3 WHERE Username = @newUser;
  DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE Username = @newUser;
  DELETE FROM Table3 WHERE Username = @newUser;
```

I'm trying to delete the fk tables first, then the primary table. Hence the reverse order.  If you care whether there were already rows in those tables, you can examine the numbers or rows affected by each query.

Next, issue your `update` statement, the one in your question.

Finally, do a commit.

```
COMMIT;
```

One more idea: if the `@newUser` already exists, you could consider changing that username to some made-up string, like `former_user_12345` rather than deleting the rows.